# Use PythonVirtualenvOperator in Apache Airflow 2.0 TaskFlow DAG

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `PythonVirtualenvOperator` inside of a DAG that I'm creating, using the TaskFlow API in Apache Airflow 2.0.1.

#### Sample Code

Here's what my sample DAG looks like:

```py
from time import sleep
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator

default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow'
}

@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2), tags = ['trevor'])
def trevor_dag():
  @task()
  def task1():
    sleep(2)
    return 'hi'
  t_task1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(python_callable=task1, system_site_packages=False, requirements=['boto3', 'apache-airflow'], task_id='trevor')
  

mydag = trevor_dag()
```

#### Expected Result

DAG executes successfully in a Python virtual environment.

#### Actual Result

It seems that, even though I'm installing the `apache-airflow` package into the virtual environment, it's not finding the TaskFlow API types.

```
[2021-04-06 22:44:19,324] {process_utils.py:135} INFO - Executing cmd: /tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/bin/python /tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.py /tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.in /tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.out /tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/string_args.txt
[2021-04-06 22:44:19,329] {process_utils.py:137} INFO - Output:
[2021-04-06 22:44:19,722] {process_utils.py:141} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-04-06 22:44:19,723] {process_utils.py:141} INFO -   File "/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.py", line 28, in <module>
[2021-04-06 22:44:19,723] {process_utils.py:141} INFO -     @task()
[2021-04-06 22:44:19,724] {process_utils.py:141} INFO - NameError: name 'task' is not defined
[2021-04-06 22:44:20,059] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - Command '['/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/bin/python', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.py', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.in', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.out', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1112, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 493, in execute
    super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 117, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 531, in execute_callable
    string_args_filename,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 145, in execute_in_subprocess
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/bin/python', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.py', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.in', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/script.out', '/tmp/venvgjg2bsg6/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2021-04-06 22:44:20,061] {taskinstance.py:1503} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=trevor_dag, task_id=trevor, execution_date=20210406T224317, start_date=20210406T224317, end_date=20210406T224420
```

**Question**: How do I properly utilize the `PythonVirtualenvOperator` in DAGs built on the Airflow 2.x TaskFlow API?

Answer (score 7):

[`PythonVirtualenvOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.PythonVirtualenvOperator) expects a function to be executed as an argument to its `python_callable` parameter. Since you use the `task` decorator on `task1()`, what `PythonVirtualenvOperator` gets instead is an Airflow operator (and not the function `task1()`). You need to remove that `task` decorator.

Also, `task1()` will be "cut out" from the DAG and executed in a virtual environment on its own. So, you have to [do all necessary imports inside the function](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator). I.e., importing `sleep()`.

The following DAG will work as expected:

```python
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator

default_args = {"owner": "airflow"}


@dag(
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=["trevor"],
)
def trevor_dag():
    def task1():
        from time import sleep

        sleep(100)
        return "hi"

    t_task1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        python_callable=task1,
        system_site_packages=False,
        requirements=["boto3", "apache-airflow"],
        task_id="trevor",
    )


mydag = trevor_dag()
```

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolesnikov , I assume this code is run using the airflow server's resources?

Comment: @lppier Where and how the code of `task1()` is run depends on the configured [executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/index.html). It can be a process on the Airflow server, a K8s pod, etc.